# VLC Only Using Up One Core

Tags: vlc-media-player, debian-wheezy

I'm using Debian Wheezy with KDE 4.8. It comes with VLC 2.0.3 Twoflower and Dragon Player 4.8.4.

Most 1080p videos (especially those with WMV3 video stream or MKV) stutter heavily and are not watchable in VLC, but play smoothly in Dragon Player. I found out that VLC only maxes out one core and leaves the other one almost idle when playing these videos. Dragon Player, on the other hand, always uses both cores almost equally regardless of quality and codec.

Are there settings in VLC that I can change to allow smooth 1080p playback?

My Computer:

- Intel Core 2 Duo T5500
- Intel GM965/GL960 (according to lspci)
- 3GB RAM
- 200GB Hitachi 5400RPM drive

Comment: not too sure on nix, but on Mac & Win, early VLC v2's were a bit clunky. Try a newer version, [or even older]